# Surface area of cone using Dirac delta and volume integral

Tags: calculus, integration, dirac-delta, surface-integrals

I want to find the surface area of a cone (excluding the circular 'base') by doing a volume integral with the appropriate Dirac delta. Schematically

$$
\text{Area}=\int d\text{Vol} \ \delta(...)
$$

Let the cone have height $h$ and maximum radius $R=1$. The correct area is $A=\pi \sqrt{1+h^2}$. I put the pointy end at the origin and align the cone with the $z$ axis.

In Cartesian co-ordinates, I have tried

$$ 
A \stackrel{?}{=}\int dx \ dy \int\limits_0^h dz \ \delta \left( z-h\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right)
=\int\limits_{h\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<h} dx \ dy =\pi \neq A 
$$

As pointed out in the comments, the correct expression should be

$$\tag{1}
A=\int dx \ dy \int\limits_0^h dz \ \left[ \delta \left( z-h\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right) \sqrt{1+h^2}\right]
$$

In spherical co-ordinates, I find by comparing to the correct answer

$$\tag{2}
\int d\theta \ d\phi \int\limits_0^L dr  \ r^2\sin\theta \left[ \frac{\delta(\theta-\theta_0)}{r} \right]=A
$$

Where $L=\sqrt{1+h^2}$ and $\sin \theta_0=1/L$. I am unable to 'derive' (or even intuit) the terms in $[ ...]$ in eq (1) and eq (2). What I know:

1. The 'composition with a function' property of the delta.
2. The delta picks up an inverse Jacobian under co-ordinate transforms.
3. It is necessary to integrate out singular variables in the Jacobian eg. for a point at the origin in spherical co-ordinates.
4. It is necessary to be careful when using the [delta to find areas or lengths](https://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath663/kmath663.htm).

**Question: How to derive (by means other than 'comparing to the correct answer') the expressions in eq. (1) and eq. (2) which include factors appended to the deltas?**

Comment: For (1) you can take $\sqrt{1+h^2} \, \delta(z-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ or, if you don't want factors in front of $\delta,$
$$\delta\left(\frac{z-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{1+h^2}}\right).$$

Comment: @md2perpe Thank you. Any idea how one would go about deriving this expression?

Comment: The cone area is
$$
A 
= \iint_{x^2+y^2\leq z^2} \sqrt{1+h^2} \, dx \, dy 
.
$$

Insert a unit, $1=\int_{\mathbb{R}} \delta(z-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) \, dz$ to get
$$
A = \iiint_{x^2+y^2\leq 1, z\in\mathbb{R}} \sqrt{1+h^2} \, \delta(z-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) \, dx \, dy \, dz
.
$$
Then use that $\delta(ax)=\frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x)$ to rewrite $\sqrt{1+h^2} \, \delta(z-\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ as $\delta\left(\frac{z-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\sqrt{1+h^2}}\right).$

Comment: @md2perpe What I mean is: "derive without knowing the answer beforehand"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem**
Let $\Omega$ be a set with piecewise smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$. Let $\mathbf{n}$ be the outbound normal field on $\partial\Omega$ and $S$ be the area measure on $\partial\Omega.$ Then $\nabla \mathbf{1}_\Omega = -\mathbf{n}S,$ where $\mathbf{1}_\Omega$ is the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) on $\Omega$.

**Proof**
Let $\varphi$ be a test function. Then,
$$
\langle \nabla\mathbf{1}_\Omega, \varphi \rangle
= -\langle \mathbf{1}_\Omega, \nabla\varphi \rangle
= -\int_\Omega \nabla\varphi \, dV
= -\oint_{\partial\Omega} \varphi \, \mathbf{n}\,dS
= \langle -\mathbf{n}\,dS, \varphi \rangle.
$$

---

The indicator function on the inner of the cone can be written as $u(x,y,z) = H(z-h\rho),$ where $\rho=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$ The gradient then is
$$
\nabla u = 
-\frac{hx}{\rho}\delta(z-h\rho) \,\hat{x}
-\frac{hy}{\rho}\delta(z-h\rho) \,\hat{y}
+\delta(z-h\rho) \,\hat{z}
$$
which gives that the area measure is given by the distribution
$S=|\nabla u| = \sqrt{1+h^2} \delta(z-h\rho).$

---

In polar coordinates the indicator function can be written as $u(r,\theta,\phi)=H(\theta_0-\theta)$ which has gradient
$$
\nabla u = -\frac{1}{r}\delta(\theta_0-\theta)\,\hat{\theta}
$$
giving the area measure distribution $S=|\nabla u| = \frac{1}{r}\delta(\theta_0-\theta).$

Comment: This is precisely the sort of thing I was looking for. Thank you!