# Product of composition of Dirac Delta functions

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, definite-integrals, dirac-delta

I am wrestling with an integral of the following form:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^4} d\textbf{x}\: f(\textbf{x})\delta(g(\textbf{x}))\delta(h(\textbf{x}))$$

Where $\textbf{x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, $h(x)=x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4$ and $g(x)$ is smooth almost everywhere. I additionally have a parameterization of the system

$$\begin{cases}
g(\textbf{x})=0\\
h(\textbf{x})=0
\end{cases}$$

Via Wikipedia I am aware of the formula for a single dimensional Delta function with a scalar substitution

$$\int d\textbf{x}\: f(\textbf{x})\delta(g(\textbf{x}))=\int_{g^{-1}(0)}\frac{f(\textbf{x})}{|\nabla g(\textbf{x})|}d\sigma(\textbf{x})$$

However it has been challenging to find information on generalizations to higher order Delta functions.

Any resources or analysis would be appreciated!

Comment: Generally speaking the product of delta functions doesn't make sense. Where does this come from?

Comment: It comes from weak turbulence theory, in particular the kinetic equation [On bottom p 6 here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2399-6528/abb4b7/pdf). To an extent I am thinking of it as a 2-D delta function, ie we consider the mapping to the manifold (g(x),h(x)) and take our delta function on that. But I am not thoroughly educated in distributions.

Comment: Would it be better to think of one of the delta functions purely as a constraint as opposed to a true delta function and proceed accordingly?

Comment: The formula you're looking for is$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\delta(g(\mathbf{x}))\delta(h(\mathbf{x}))d\mathbf{x}=\int_{g^{-1}(0)\cap h^{-1}(0)}\frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{\|\nabla g(\mathbf{x})\times\nabla h(\mathbf{x})\|}ds$$ but deriving it requires a bit of background. In particular, you need to define the Dirac delta in such a way that the above integral makes sense, and then show that the resulting integrals obey the [change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables).

Comment: I don't see what's preventing OP applying his formula twice (there also seems to be an extra $\vec{x}$ in the equation. It's actually quite intuitive; just like $\delta(x)\delta(y)$ would restrict you to a 2 dimensional plane if you're working in $\mathbb{R}^4$; then $\delta(h(x))\delta(g(x))$ would restrict you to a curved surface if, again, you're working in $\mathbb{R}^4$. This can be seen from OP's formula directly by applying it twice (though again there's an extra factor which shouldn't be there).

Comment: @kajelad Many thanks! While I am sure the machinery is nightmarish the generalization makes intuitive sense ie just moving the surface integral divisor up by a dimension while treating the arguments of the delta functions as a parameterization of some kind. Do you have a source for the analysis? If I feel like some self punishment later this week I'd like to take a peek. 

Also, if you write this up with a source as a solution I will very happily select it!

Comment: @Leonid, First off, thanks for the typo catch : ). I was initially going to just integrate it down to 2-D, but I saw hints of a more general formula in some sources. Additionally, the problem I am working with can be generalized to have additional nontrivial delta terms, so I wanted to sniff around for more general solutions.

Comment: @NickS I misread your question as being in $\mathbb{R}^3$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^4$; I believe the more general form should read$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^4}f(\mathbf{x})\delta(g(\mathbf{x}))\delta(h(\mathbf{x}))d\mathbf{x}=\int_{g^{-1}(0)\cap h^{-1}(0)}\frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{\|dg(\mathbf{x})\wedge dh(\mathbf{x})\|}dA$$

Comment: @Kajelad, Thanks, I appreciate the followup, I was actually going to inquire about that shortly. Do you have a reference I can read for this? I would like to learn the mechanics, and most sources I have found don't go this far.

Comment: @Kajelad Sorry to bug you, but can I have a source?

Comment: @NickS Possibly irrelevant, but if what you want is the integral of $f$ over the surface defined by $h=0=g$, I think that your first expression isn't correct (I [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4250607/surface-area-of-cone-using-dirac-delta-and-volume-integral) a similar question some time ago).

Comment: @Sal, Thanks for the followup, but unfortunately in my case the presence of the dual delta functions results from a limiting process and are a necessary part of the model as interpreted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a good reference for the formula I gave; here's an explanation instead, (albeit a somewhat hand-waving one).

If integrals like the one you gave are well defined, multiplying by $\delta(x_i)$ where $x_i$ is a coordinate ought be the same as setting those coordinates to zero:
$$
\int_{U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^3}f(x_1,x_2,x_3)\delta(x_2)\delta(x_3)dx_1dx_2dx_3=\int_{\{x_1\in\mathbb{R}:(x_1,0,0)\in U\}}f(x_1,0,0)dx_1
$$
and so on for other dimensions and other numbers of deltas. Additionally, we would expect such integrals to still obey the change of variables formula:
$$
\int_Vf(\mathbf{x})d\mathbf{x}=\int_Uf(\varphi(\mathbf{y}))|\det(D\varphi(\mathbf{y}))|d\mathbf{y}
$$
Where $\varphi:U\to V$ is a diffeomorphism between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

If we assume that the zero sets of $g$ and $h$ are transverse (i.e. $\nabla g$ and $\nabla h$ are linearly independent on $g^{-1}(0)\cap h^{-1}(0)$), then this is already enough. Let $\mathbf{p}\in g^{-1}(0)\cap h^{-1}(0)$. By inverse function theorem there exist a set of local coordinates $\mathbf{y}:V\to U$ on a neighborhood $V$ of $\mathbf{p}$ such that $\mathbf{y}(p)=\mathbf{0}$, $y_3=g$, and $y_4=h$. Let $\varphi:U\to V$ be the inverse of these coordinates. Applying the change of variables formula gives
$$
\int_Vf(\mathbf{x})\delta(g(\mathbf{x}))\delta(h(\mathbf{x}))d\mathbf{x}=\int_Uf(\varphi(\mathbf{y}))\delta(g(\varphi(\mathbf{y}
))\delta(h(\varphi(\mathbf{y}))|\det(D\varphi(\mathbf{y})|d\mathbf{y}
$$
Since $\varphi$ is inverse to $\mathbf{y}$, we can rewrite this as
$$
=\int_U\frac{f(\varphi(\mathbf{y}))\delta(y_3)\delta(y_4)}{|\det(D\mathbf{y}(\varphi(\mathbf{y})))|}d\mathbf{y}
$$
Now that the deltas are composed with coordinates, we can restrict to a surface integral.
$$
=\int_{U\cap\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{f(\varphi(y_1,y_2,0,0))}{|\det(D\mathbf{y}(\varphi(y_1,y_2,0,0)))|}dy_1dy_2
$$
The columns of $D\mathbf{y}$ are just the gradients of the coordinates.
$$
=\int_{U\cap\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{f(\varphi(\mathbf{y}))\delta(y_3)\delta(y_4)}{|\det([\nabla y_1,\nabla y_2,\nabla g,\nabla h])|(\varphi(y_1,y_2,0,0))}dy_1dy_2
$$
Let $\pi$ be the orthogonal projection onto $T(g^{-1}(0)\cap h^{-1}(0))$. Since this amounts to subtracting multiples of $\nabla g$ and $\nabla h$, we can apply it to $\nabla y_1$ and $\nabla y_2$ without changing the determinant:
$$
=\int_{U\cap\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{f(\varphi(y_1,y_2,0,0))}{|\det([\pi(\nabla y_1),\pi(\nabla y_2),\nabla g,\nabla h])|(\varphi(y_1,y_2,0,0))}dy_1dy_2
$$
To split the determinant, note that $|\det([a,b,c,d])|$ is equal to the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by $a,b,c,d$. If $\operatorname{span}(a,b)\perp\operatorname{span}(c,d)$, then this is equal to the product of areas the parallelograms spanned by $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$. In terms of wedge products, this gives
$$
=\int_{U\cap\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{f(\varphi(y_1,y_2,0,0))}{\|\nabla g\wedge\nabla h\|(\varphi(y_1,y_2,0,0))}\frac{dy_1dy_2}{\|\pi(\nabla y_1)\wedge\pi(\nabla y_2)\|(\varphi(y_1,y_2,0,0))}
$$
Where the last term is just the standard area element of $g^{-1}(0)\cap h^{-1}(0)$ in the coordinates $y_1,y_2$. Writing this in a more coordinate-independent way, we (almost) have the desired formula.
$$
=\int_{V\cap(g^{-1}(0)\cap h^{-1}(0))}\frac{f}{\|\nabla g\wedge\nabla h\|}dA
$$
This result is only local, but you can recover the global version using a partition of unity.

Comment: Thank you so much for your work in explaining this, I really appreciate it and it is very clear!

I am starting to dig into some sources on integrating over a pullback map of a functional, which appears to give this formally (Though nowhere near as intuitively as written here). If I end up understanding it formally, I will come back with some sources if you are interested.